# How would you write this code recursively?

Tags: java

I wrote this code myself but I'm new with recursion and I need some help with changing this code so it would be recursive. I started out with a base case. I was trying to write code that checks two strings and sees if its identical.

```
    public static boolean check(String s1, String s2) {
    int count = 0;
    if (s1.length() != s2.length()) {
        return false;
    else {
       for (int i=0; i< s1.length(); i++){
           if(s1.charAt(i) != s2.charAt(i)) 
                return false;
           count = i;
       }
       if(count == s1.length()-1)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: In real life you'll use `String#equals(..)`

Comment: This case isn't very well suited for recursion and the iterative approach is almost always better, if you're looking for recursion examples I would suggest looking for simple tree searching examples such as navigating a binary tree

Comment: use equals() or eqaulsIgnoreCase() Mehthod of java.lang.String

Answer (score 2):

The `count` variable is unnecessary. You can replace the `for` loop with a recursive call:

```
public static boolean check(String s1, String s2) {
    if (s1.length() != s2.length())
        return false;
    return check(s1, s2, 0);
}

private static boolean check(String s1, String s2, int i) {
    // this is up to you
    return check(s1, s2, i+1);
}
```

**Edit:** just saw the homework tag

Comment: it is isnt hw someone just freakin tagged it as

Comment: It most definitely *is* homework. Your inability to parse my complete answer proves it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont want to write this in java here is the algo that you can follo:

```
compare(s1, s2, index)
begin
if(s1.charAt(index)==s2.charAt(index))
   return compare(s1,s2,index+1);
else 
   return false;
end
```

to this you have to add the boundary condition now that is check if index  exceeds length

Comment: btw recursion is not the best possible soln here

Comment: your answer's comment has the style, I like it. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is [properly tail recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call):

```
class strcmp {

private static boolean inner_check(String s1, String s2, int n) {
  if (n == s1.length())
    return true;
  if (s1.charAt(n) != s2.charAt(n))
    return false;
  return inner_check(s1, s2, n + 1);
}

public static boolean check(String s1, String s2) {
  if (s1.length() != s2.length())
    return false;
  return inner_check(s1, s2, 0);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  if (args.length < 2) {
    System.out.println("provide two arguments");
    return;
  }
  System.out.println(check(args[0], args[1]));
}
}
```

Comment: what do you mean when by saying provide 2 arguements

Answer (score 0):

Hey recursive means function call itself,if you are using recursive call you should care that recursive call should never go infinite, means we need to put some check point to avoid infinite loop execution.

In your code, you never call "check(String args1,String args2)" inside check(Strings,String s2) itself so it is not recursive.

I am giving you simple example of recursive call

```
public  boolean check(int s1, int s2) {
   boolean b=s1>s2;
   if(b)
   {
       return b;
   }
   else
   {
     return  check(s1,s2-1);    //here
   }

}
```

You can see in check call itself (marked in comment here) .

Answer (score 0):

You have some answers here which show you the recursive code. I just wanted to add, since you are just learning to write recursive code, you need to first understand how the process works and how it should be done.
**Example:** You should first write the base case which does not make recursive calls to prevent infinite recursions.
Read [this](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2002/cmsc214/Tutorial/recursion2.html), it would give you a better insight.